# Thermodynamics behind positive Enthalpy and Volume change of mixing for mixtures showing large positive deviation from roult's law

Tags: thermodynamics

At onset let me make it very clear that similar questions do exist already on chemistry SE site, but none of them has a kind of answer I expect, hence I ought to start a discussion here.

As per my understanding

$\Delta H_{mix}=-RT\Sigma (\frac{\delta ln(a_{i})}{\delta ln(T)})_P,{x_{i}}$

$\Delta V_{mix}=\frac{RT}{P}\Sigma (\frac{\delta ln(a_{i})}{\delta ln(P)})_T,{x_{i}}$

Literature I am referring to reads

> Positive deviation occurs when the interaction between unlike molecules is weaker than interaction between like molecules.The solutions of this type are characterized by positive Enthalpy of mixing and positive volume of mixing.

I want to know what is the physics point of view (mathematical reasoning as well as intuition) behind this statement? How the equations (stated above) predict this behaviour?

Comment: A-A and B-B interactions are preferred, so forcing A-B interactions means higher enthalpy, and the A-B pairs are farther apart (repulsive not attractive force) so the volume goes up.